# How to properly save an image from android device into bitmap file?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, .net-standard

I am creating an application with Xamarin.Android that sends an image from the camera to a web API, and on server side that image have to be saved.

I have already written server server side code and in the android application I receive image as byte array through `IPreviewCallback`.

Camera picture format is set to:
`ImageFormatType.Rgb565`

Image save method on server:

```
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565))
            {
                var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
                BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);
                IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

                Marshal.Copy(data, 0, ptr, data.Length);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                bmp.Save(filePath);
            }
```

The result of these actions is that colors of saved bitmap does not correspond with image from android emulator:

[Inout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbqeH.png)

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6uLe.png)

I tried with success to get image from YUV image to JPEG, but for my purpose i need uncompressed bitmap.

If you need some more information, please do not hesitate to ask :)

Comment: you posted two copies of the same image

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question.